# RequireJS Dynamic Paths Replacement

Tags: requirejs, amd

I have a requirejs module which is used as a wrapper to an API that comes from a different JS file:

**apiWrapper.js**

```
define([], function () {
    return {
        funcA: apiFuncA,
        funcB: apiFuncB
    };
});
```

It works fine but now I have some new use cases where I need to replace the implementation, e.g. instead of apiFuncA invoke my own function. But I don't want to touch other places in my code, where I call the functions, like `apiWrapper.funcA(param)`.

I can do something like the following:

```
define([], function () {
    return {
        funcA: function(){
            if(regularUseCase){
                return apiFuncA(arguments);
            } else {
                return (function myFuncAImplementation(params){
                    //my code, instead of the external API
                })(arguments);
            }
        },
        funcB: apiFuncB
    };
});
```

But I feel like it doesn't look nice. What's a more elegant alternative? Is there a way to replace the module (apiWrapper) dynamically? Currently it's defined in my require.config paths definition. Can this path definition be changed at runtime so that I'll use a different file as a wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, if you use Require.js, you probably want to build it before production. As so, it is important you don't update paths dynamically at runtime or depends on runtime variables to defines path as this will prevent you from running r.js successfully.

There's a lot of tools (requirejs plugins) out there that can help you dynamically change the path to a module or conditionnaly load a dependency.

First, you could use [require.replace](https://github.com/SBoudrias/require.replace) that allow you to change parts (or all) of a module URL depending on a check you made without breaking the build.

If you're looking for polyfilling, there's [requirejs feature](https://github.com/jensarps/AMD-feature)

And there's a lot more listed here: https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Plugins